# How add expression of where for generic type?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I need to check entity in geenric service if it is Entity type, I should add dynamic expression where `.Where("IsDeleted==false");`

```
var result = _entityRepo.All();

var isEntityType = typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
if (isEntityType)
{
    var expression = CreateExpression("IsDeleted", true);
    var casted = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)expression;
    result = result.Where(casted);
}
return result;
```

`_entityRepo` is `GenericRepository<T>`

```
public static Expression CreateExpression(string propertyName, bool valueToCompare)
{
    // get the type of entity
    var entityType = typeof(Entity);
    // get the type of the value object
    var entityProperty = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    // Expression: "entity"
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

    // check if the property type is a value type
    // only value types work
    // Expression: entity.Property == value
    return Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(parameter, entityProperty),
        Expression.Constant(valueToCompare)
    );
}
```

off course I get error on cast:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MadCloud.Domain.Auditing.AuditCategory,System.Boolean]]'.

Comment: You don't really need nor want expression magic for this. Just use an `IDeletableEntity` interface that declares the `IsDeleted` property.

Comment: Could you please tell more?

Comment: Maybe you should make it less generic and define a BaseEntity that supports the IsDeleted option.

Comment: Probably your problem goes deeper: What is about NavigationProperties which should be checked for IsDeleted. If that is the case, then possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12760933/3411327

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `IsDeleted` is part of the Entity type, just cast to it:

```
IEnumerable<T> result = _entityRepo.All();
bool isEntityType = typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
if (isEntityType)
{
    result = result.Where(x => ((Entity)(object)x).IsDeleted == true);
}
return result;
```

After all, you know that `Entity` is assignable from `T`, so you can make the cast. Note that you need to cast it first to `object` in order to disable the compiler’s type checks at compile time. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7978447/216074).

Comment: I tried it. error on build: can't cast T to Entity type

Comment: You can do `((Entity)(object)x).IsDeleted` then.