# Create factory that will return object of generic abstract type in .net core

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I'm creating code that is using abstract generic class as base. I got a little stuck since I'm try to create factory that will return specific object base on inserted object type.

Lets say that i want to compare to object to check are they are equal or not. In my scenario i want to compare object in way base on that if they are type of `IEnumerable` or `IList`

My code :

Interface :

```
public interface IObjectComparer<in T>
{
    bool Compare(T obj1, T obj2);
}
```

Base class :

```
public abstract class ObjectComparerBase<T> : IObjectComparer<T>
{
    public abstract bool Compare(T obj1, T obj2);

    public void SomeUsefullHelperMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

`IList` object comparer :

```
public sealed class ListObjectComparer : ObjectComparerBase<IList>
{
    public override bool Compare(IList obj1, IList obj2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and `IEnumerable` object comparer

```
public sealed class EnumerableObjectComparer : ObjectComparerBase<IEnumerable>
{ 
    public override bool Compare(IEnumerable obj1, IEnumerable obj2)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

At the end i have my factory that should decide if which comparer i need to use for certain object :

```
public sealed class ComparerRetriever
{
    public static IObjectComparer<T> Retrieve<T>(T obj)
    {
        IObjectComparer<T> comparer = null;
        switch (typeof(T))
        {
            case IEnumerable o:
            {
                comparer = new EnumerableObjectComparer();
                break;
            }

            case IList o:
            {
                comparer = new ListObjectComparer();
                break;
            }

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Not Supported Type");
        }

        return comparer;
    }
}
```

My problem :

In current scenario i cannot use my `ComparerRetriever` class because compilator is say that nether `ListObjectComparer` nor  `EnumerableObjectComparer` is not `IObjectComparer<T>` type.

My question is why ? My objects are have `ObjectComparerBase<T>` class as a parent and this class is implementing `IObjectComparer<T>` so in my opinion `EnumerableObjectComparer` and `ListObjectComparer` should be type of `ObjectComparerBase<T>`

Probably I'm missing something but at this point I cannot see what.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't understand the link between the type of `T`, the `case` and your constructed types. The only way to construct and return those, assuming the types really do match, is to do `return (IObjectComparer<T>)(object)new EnumerableObjectComparer();` (I believe the mid-cast to `object` is necessary but try without)

Comment: This Cast is Helping in that scenario. I also needed this mid-cast. I think that this is good answer. Maybe code will not look best by this cast but at least i till compile.

Comment: Related: [Why do I have to cast twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978316/cannot-convert-type-why-is-it-necesssary-to-cast-twice)

Answer (score 0):

So this works and returns the classes as expected. You will have to put IList first because IList implements IEnumerable and if IEnumerable is first it will also fall to that case.

```
public sealed class ComparerRetriever
{
    public static IObjectComparer<T> Retrieve<T>(T obj)
    {
        IObjectComparer<T> comparer;
        switch (typeof(T))
        {
            case IList o:
            {
                comparer = new ListObjectComparer() as IObjectComparer<T>;
                break;
            }
            case IEnumerable o:
            {
                comparer = new EnumerableObjectComparer() as IObjectComparer<T>;
                break;
            }


            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Not Supported Type");
        }

        return comparer;
    }
}
```

I do think though that you will always hit the default case as any object you pass to the `Retrieve` method as it will have a concrete type and the `typeof` will result in that concrete type not the Intreface

For instance when I did my testing I created

```
class SimpleList : IList
{
   ... blah
}
```

and predictably the `typeof` call resulted in SimpleList and not IList so it always threw

`NotSupportedException("Not Supported Type");`

obviously I could be wrong and you could be one step ahead of me so I'll leave my answer there as I believe I've answered the original question

UPDATE
After more testing I'm not sure you can use pattern matching on interfaces, I have since changed my implementation to the below and I still hit the default case.

```
public static IObjectComparer<T> Retrieve<T>(T obj)
{
    IObjectComparer<T> comparer;

    var interf = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();
    switch (interf)
    {
        case IList o:
        {
            comparer = new ListObjectComparer() as IObjectComparer<T>;
            break;
        }
        case IEnumerable o:
        {
            comparer = new EnumerableObjectComparer() as IObjectComparer<T>;
            break;
        }


        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Not Supported Type");
    }

    return comparer;
}
```