# Usage of generic type for explicit conversion

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have a code snippet:

```
public interface IMyInternalClass
{
}

public class MyInternalClass : IMyInternalClass
{
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    T GetInternalObject<T>();
}

public class MyClass: IMyClass
{
    private readonly MyInternalClass _internalObject;

    public T GetInternalObject<T>()
    {
        return (T)(IMyInternalClass)_internalObject;
    }

    public MyClass(MyInternalClass internalObject)
    {
        _internalObject = internalObject;
    }
}
```

The `GetInternalObject<T>` usage:

```
IMyInternalClass internalObject = myClass?.GetInternalObject<IMyInternalClass>();
```

If I try to use explicit conversion by `return (T)_internalObject;` - it will not work and will fail with error "*Cannot convert type 'MyInternalClass' to 'T'*"

So, without touching the design of this code example, why do I does it works with explicit conversion to `(IMyInternalClass)` first?

> There is another question [Cannot convert type: why is it necesssary
>   to cast twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978316/cannot-convert-type-why-is-it-necesssary-to-cast-twice) but there is no information regarding interface usage as
>   in this case.

Comment: you are not actually using `IMyClass` anywhere

Comment: do you you miss adding `: IMyClass` to the class def for MyClass?

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't know 'T' is the same type, and how should it?

Comment: "So, without touching the design of this code example" - But the problem **is** the design of the code example. I'm sorry, but when you have a faulty design, you must either change it or jump through hoops.

Comment: Shouldn´t `MyClass` implement `IMyClass`?

Comment: Edited. Yes, I missed it when writing question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do you need to cast to `object` first?

`_internalObject` is of type `MyInternalClass`, and you are trying to cast this to `T`. `T` can be any type, so the compiler thought, "I'm pretty sure you certainly can't cast `MyInternalClass` to any type.". If you cast it to `object` first, then the compiler thinks "this value of type `object` can be any type at runtime, so it can be casted to any type."

Here's another explanation using the spec if you are not satisfied.

According to the C# spec, section 6.2.7, "Explicit conversions involving type parameters":

> Explicit reference conversions
>
> The following explicit conversions exist for a given type parameter T:
>
> - From the effective base class C of T to T and from any base class of C to T. At run-time, if T is a value type, the conversion is executed as an unboxing conversion. Otherwise, the conversion is executed as an explicit reference conversion or identity conversion.
> - From any interface type to T. At run-time, if T is a value type, the conversion is executed as an unboxing conversion. Otherwise, the conversion is executed as an explicit reference conversion or identity conversion.
> - ...

The effective base class of `T` is `object`, which is why you can do this cast.

---

That said, what you are doing here seems like a bad idea. This code is very type unsafe. You can pass any type into `T`, but only things like `object`, `IMyInternalClass` and `MyInternalClass` works for `T`.

Therefore, this seems like a misuse of generics. You should just return a `MyInternalClass` or `IMyInternalClass`:

```
public MyInternalClass GetInternalObject()
{
    return _internalObject;
}
// or
public IMyInternalClass GetInternalObject()
{
    return _internalObject;
}
```

Comment: Since there is `IMyInternalClass` interface, it would be more convenient to return that instead

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I suspect that the reason why OP used generics in the first place is because he wants to assign the return value to both a variable of type `MyInternalClass` and `IMyInternalClass`. That's why I chose to return `MyInternalClass`, but I guess you have a point as well.

Comment: I am unsure that the first explanatioon is enough. Because I can use 'return (T)(IMyInternalClass)_internalObject' and it will work fine. But the compiler should probably argue about it.

Comment: @Belurd Yeah, that's why I added quotes from the spec. I have quoted more of the spec to show why `return (T)(IMyInternalClass)_internalObject;` works.

Comment: @Sweeper Regarding the last part - the question is not about design of the code. I just want to understand how it works with generics in this case.

Comment: @Sweeper Taking into consideration what you wroke from spec I can't understand why it is not work in the first place. Could you explain it better please?

Comment: @Belurd basically, when the spec says “there is an explicit conversion from T to U”, that means you can cast from T and U. If it doesn’t say, you can’t.

Comment: @Sweeper I understand it. But why does it work with `return (T)(IMyInternalClass)_internalObject`? There is no explicit conversion from IMyInternalClass to T as I understand.

Comment: @Belurd look at the second bullet point in the quote: “from any interface type to T”

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. I have changed question so that it is pointing to specifically the case where there is conversion from interface to T.